# Finding the True Option Value

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options, valuation, european-options

Many research papers use differing solution methods to attempt to find the 'true' value of an option whether it be Euro, American, etc.

They never mention how they do find the true option value to test against however. Which becomes my question: how does one find the true value of an option for given input variables to test against?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your model? Is there a close form solution for options in your model ?

Comment: Without any dynamics we can't speak  correctly.

Comment: This is specifically regarding American Puts for which there is not a closed form solution, as of the work I've looked into. With regards to dynamics, that is an input in itself surely? If I was to say I was using risk neutral dynamics would that really help considering I'm trying to approximate a true value with those assumed dynamics.

Comment: Hint: What is the *true* value of a stock?

Comment: Basically this answers your question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/6990/12

Comment: Basically you're saying the true value is inferred from market value of the option? Surely this is not true value but perceived value? Much the logic of an over/under valuation of a stock per say? @vonjd

Comment: @vonjd The true value of stock is irrelevant here.

Comment: What is relevant then @WillGu

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the broad sense, you were wondering what is the true or exact value of the solution if some equation has no analytic solution. I think that basically there's no true value, only approximate value up to some precision threshold. If you make this threshold infinitely small, you can approach to the exact value. It definitely depends on the dynamics (differential equation itself). Different numerical methods applied to the same equation should agree with each other.

Comment: and @BehrouzMaleki was on the point, too. We can only compare true values within the same dynamics, e.g. BS with constant vol and mean-reverting vol would almost certainly give different results (whether analytic solution exists or not)

Comment: You slightly contradict yourself. What is "within some precision threshold" if like you said you don't know the true value? What are you converging on? I understand for different inputs you'll get different outcomes. It's more to the point of how one model can state it's superiority over another with no recognition of what a true value is y'know.

Comment: @ Will Gu  I don't agree.

Comment: Other people have noted it above too, but the "true value" of anything is what you can sell or trade it for. The moment you start talking about statistics or probabilities, you are speculating.

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful your upvoting and accepting it is appreciated - Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Basically it boils down to this:

You either use a descriptive or a prescriptive (normative) model, i.e. you either think that the market is always right or you think that you alone know how to determine the "true" price of an option.

The original idea of BS was to build a prescriptive model but most modern models try to take the market prices as given and calibrate their models accordingly, thereby gaining one common variable to make all prices comparable: volatility. One prerequisite is to seek consistency for all prices which is normally done via hedging arguments (which often leads to risk-neutrality assumptions). Yet in practice even in the case of minor inconsistencies they often cannot be used to make money due to friction.

At the end it all boils down to your business model (this is what I meant with my question about the *true* value of a stock). When you are on the buy side you try to find mispriced options with a prescriptive model (so you are saying that you know which is the *true* price - and all other market participants are wrong). When you are on the sell side you use a calibrated descriptive model which mainly seeks consistency so that you can live on the spread.

(This is why I gave this link in the comments: [How do we use option price models (like Black-Scholes Model) to make money in practice?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-do-we-use-option-price-models-like-black-scholes-model-to-make-money-in-pr/6990#6990))

So in a way *truth* is relative: It either means overall consistent with the market or it means smarter than the market.